# Should the html rule be the first rule in a css document?

Tags: css

I always have added my wildcard rules `*{ }` *before* my `html{ }` rule but I've seen some people putting `html` before wildcards, so I was curious what was best practice.

Comment: The only time the order of rules matters is when the rules apply to the same elements, in which case the last rule will override the others (specificity aside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*{}` is the lowest level element selector so you should put it in top of your stylesheet so that other elsement css rules could be overridden without using `!important` easily.

For eg:

```
*{
  color: blue;
}
div{
  color: red;/*overridden color*/
}
```

Since both `*{}` and `html{}` element selector is lowest level selector you may put them in any order in top of your stylesheet. But I would prefer to use `*{}` as first rule as it denotes to all element selector.

Comment: that was what I have always done as well, but was reading [this blog entry](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) and noticed in his code `html` came first, but I guess in *that context* it's logical to put `*` *after* html since it inherits `border-box` from `html`, right?

Comment: So, you can also reverse the order and apply border-box in * selector and inherit in html selector. Both are okay...

Comment: Your second example is incorrect. The star (universal) selector has a specificity of zero so  `*` will _not_  override `div` as a selector: http://jsbin.com/juziwacaza/1/

Comment: @steveax, Oh, until today, I was unknown of that, 0 specificity, thank you so much, will update the answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Having the html rule after the wildcard is the right way, because the rules are read top-down. The other way would override your html rule.

```
*{ font-family: Sergio Ui;}
html{ font-family: Tahoma;}
```

With this html gets Tahoma font.

```
html{ font-family: Tahoma;}
*{font-family: Sergio Ui;}
```

With this html gets Sergio Ui font.